# Allow clicking "through" Tkinter window and elements

Tags: python, tkinter, overlay, tkinter-canvas

My end goal is to make a tool for game streamers to use in order to make their streams more fun. What I've created here is a Tkinter overlay which can simulate a "flashbang" effect by blinding the user temporarily via an API call. Then, they can use their streaming platform's integration to trigger this action via a donation/subscription.

This draft works perfectly as expected, except that the overlay completely blocks any type of user interaction from the underlying windows. The moment the user clicks the mouse, focus is transfered to the overlay window and away from the game/window they were interacting with before. The overlay does not steal focus on its own, only after a mouse click. I would like to disable any type of user interaction from being detected by Tkinter, so that the user can continue to play their game, or whatever they were doing without any actual physical disruption (besides, of course, the visual one).

```py
from flask import Flask
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
import pygame.mixer

app = Flask(__name__)
root = None
overlay = None
flash_flag = False

class FlashbangOverlay:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.overlay = None

    def create_overlay(self):
        self.overlay = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.overlay.overrideredirect(True)
        self.overlay.attributes('-alpha', 0)
        self.overlay.attributes('-topmost', True)

        screen_width = self.overlay.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.overlay.winfo_screenheight()
        self.overlay.geometry(f'{screen_width}x{screen_height}+0+0')

    def flash(self):
        global flash_flag
        if not flash_flag:
            flash_flag = True

            # Play the flashbang sound
            threading.Thread(target=self.play_sound).start()

            # Delay before showing the flashbang visual effect
            time.sleep(0.9)  # Adjust the delay time as needed

            self.show_flashbang()

    def play_sound(self):
        # Load and play the flashbang sound
        pygame.mixer.music.load("./audio/flash.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

    def show_flashbang(self):
        self.overlay.attributes('-alpha', 1)  # Set transparency to 1 (fully opaque)
        self.overlay.configure(bg='white')  # Set background color to white
        # make the overlay non interactive so the user can click through it to the application below but still see the flashbang effect
        self.overlay.attributes
        self.overlay.update()  # Update the overlay window to make the changes visible immediately

        self.root.after(2000, self.fade_out)

    def fade_out(self):
        alpha = 1.0
        step = 0.01

        while alpha > 0:
            self.overlay.attributes('-alpha', alpha)
            self.overlay.update()  # Update the overlay window to make the changes visible immediately
            alpha -= step
            self.overlay.after(30)  # Delay between each step

        self.overlay.attributes('-alpha', 0)  # Set transparency back to 0
        global flash_flag
        flash_flag = False

@app.route('/flashbang', methods=['GET'])
def trigger_flashbang():
    threading.Thread(target=flash_worker).start()
    return 'Flashbang triggered'

def flash_worker():
    overlay.flash()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize Pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()

    root = tk.Tk()  # Initialize the Tkinter root window
    overlay = FlashbangOverlay(root)
    overlay.create_overlay()

    threading.Thread(target=app.run).start()

    root.mainloop()
```

I attempted to set all sorts of different attributes to both the flash effect as well as the Tkinter window with no luck at all. Also, the other solutions I saw around didn't make any difference either.

Greatly appreciate any help.